# PWA app.js how to move code to many smaller files

Tags: node.js, progressive-web-apps

I've written PWA application, application isn't big, but now my app.js has 800 lines of the code. It has many methods. How to move these methods to another files divided thematically?
`require` doesn't work

Comment: Is this raw javascript with no module loader such as webpack or browserify? Are we talking only about client side code or is there server side code as well?

Comment: We are talking about client side code - app.js. I don't have webpack. Probably it's raw javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options depending on what browsers you support.

You may be able to use native support for modules. You can find more information about this in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules This would be one of the simpler solutions as it does not require any additional tooling but at this time the support outside chrome is not very good.

A second alternative is to break up your code into multiple JS files and just load them all separately. This can have performance implications but if your files are small and few it wont cause too many problems.  Just ensure that the code produced in these files put themselves onto a name object to avoid conflicts.

Ex file

```
(function() {

    window.mycode = {};
    window.mycode.func = function() {...};
})();
```

A third option is to use an existing module loader in the browser such as https://requirejs.org/

The fourth option, which is probably the most common, is to integrate a build step into your code that uses npm and a module loader such as webpack or browserify. This also lets you integrate babel which is really common among large javascript projects.  The downside is it adds a step to your deployment that needs to be run and you need to learn how to use tools like webpack(which is surprisingly complicated). However, if you do javascript dev you will need to be familiar with them eventually.